# Números romanos con funciones en Javascript

Tags: javascript, funciones

¿Cómo hago en *Javascript* para que al insertar un número cualquiera en un *prompt* lo convierta e imprima en consola, sin utilizar arreglos, usando solamente funciones?

Comment: que has intentado?

Comment: ¿Convertir a romanos? Necesitas en tu función un arreglo de caracteres romanos básicos para construir tu número.

Comment: Pues intente con areglos, pero el problema es que  como no hemos entrado en esa clase en javascript, aun no puedo usar areglos, solo funciones...

Comment: Si, creo que me tocar'a enviarla con areglos, espero me la reciban. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

como dato de valor, te digo que tu mejor herramienta como desarrollador es google! buscando me encontre con este blog con varias soluciones:
http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/javascript-roman-numeral-converter

```
function romanize (num) {
    if (!+num)
        return false;
    var digits = String(+num).split(""),
        key = ["","C","CC","CCC","CD","D","DC","DCC","DCCC","CM",
               "","X","XX","XXX","XL","L","LX","LXX","LXXX","XC",
               "","I","II","III","IV","V","VI","VII","VIII","IX"],
        roman = "",
        i = 3;
    while (i--)
        roman = (key[+digits.pop() + (i * 10)] || "") + roman;
    return Array(+digits.join("") + 1).join("M") + roman;
}
```

y como tip de busqueda, realiza las consultas en ingles ;) Saludos :D

Comment: Muchas gracias, yo tambien encontre ese, unicamente que ese incluye areglos, y aun no podemos usarlos porque no hemos entrado a esa clase en javascript

Comment: pues bajo la misma logica de los arreglos, solo compara con if el valor y asignale una letra. Aunque creo que lo que deberias de practicar es solucion de problemas, no exactamente JS

Comment: @Asher Las matrices, yo creo que son muy importantes en la programación. ¿A qué se debe el no uso de arrays?

Comment: @ArtEze segun yo creo, el debe estar estudiando una carrera orientada a la informatica, y las actividades se desarrollan en base a lo aprendido en clases, si usas algo que no se ha aprendido en clases se considera copia o una solucion no valida